# What is a less wordy way of describing how this car is situated?

Tags: expression-choice

I'm sitting on a bench in a park and I see this car sitting in the middle of a side street. Well, it's not actually in the middle of the street, but like right at the spot where you're about to make a right/left turn out onto the main road. It's been sitting there for about half an hour now. It's not an intersection where the car is at, it's just a side street that's leading off from the main road. If I were to describe what I had seen to someone else, how do I say it without sounding too wordy? For example, instead of describing all that I've just did above, is there a single expression that can describe the position of the car at where it's sitting, like "The car have been sitting at the [...] for half an hour now without moving, there have been no cars coming out or else it would have gotten chased off".

Edit: actually I've found a similar image:

[image]

Comment: Why isn't it an intersection?  One road connects to another one, doesn't it?

Comment: Perhaps a small diagram would help. I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @Kevin I don't have access to my laptop now to use Paint, I'm on my iPad unfortunately :( but it's basically a "T" shape instead of a cross of the intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In British English, the word you're looking for is ***junction***.

> **junction** *noun*
>   **1** a point where two or more things are joined:
>      *the junction of the two rivers*
>   a place where two or more roads or railway lines meet:
>      *the junction of Queen’s Road and Lancaster Avenue*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/junction)

> The car has been sitting at the junction for half an hour without moving.

Comment: It's obviously not exactly [Clapham Junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapham_Junction_railway_station), then! :)

Comment: I agree, but I thought that *junction* in BrE is equivalent to *intersection* in AmE, and OP says "It's not an intersection". Have I misunderstood the Q. or are *junction* & *intersection* not the same? Does *intersection have to be a *crossroads*?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood the meaning of intersection. I have always thought that intersections are always two roads that cross each other and in my case since the side street didn't cross the main road I thought it's not an intersection, my mistake -.-"

Comment: The one in the picture is a T-junction.